# How Secure Is Tails Encryption?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, tails-os

I know. Tails itself is a very secure operating system, but what about its drive encryption? I would like to encrypt my flash drive with the tails built in drive encryption. What does it use? AES-256?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/encrypted_volumes/index.en.html), Tails uses [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) through its [LUKS front-end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup). This is the standard for disk encryption under Linux.

LUKS offers a choice of ciphers; the defaults are good (AES-256, CBC or XTS depending on the version, PBKDF2 for password hashing).